# '%deb%' is showing up as '�b%' when I send a $_GET a query?

Tags: php, html, sql, css

i'm building a query on a search page based on user inputs, i then send the query to the original page and use it to query the database.

when the user enters 'deb' into the search field, the query on the results page is showing '�b%' in place of Deb. I don't know why this is happening. I'm using LIKE and UNION two tables, but it works fine with every other value.

is '%de' a reserved character or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like URL encoding is going on, you need to pass %25deb%25. %25 is the code for a percent sign